# CSS on INPUT element not rendering correctly

Tags: html, css

The problem I have is that my input fields are not being rendered correctly. The span tag appears to be below the input.

I've tried setting the z-index of span to a large number
making the borders of the input transparent

[image: When input is selected, there is a border and unselected has the input's borders on top of the span border and not rendering it correctly]

```css
span.currencyinput {
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-width: 1px;
  height: 24px;
  margin: 5px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 170px;
  z-index: 3;
}

span.currencyinput>input {
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: -6px;
  border-style: double;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: transparent;
  width: 160px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.currencyinput {
  border: 1px inset #ccc;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  position: relative;
  /* //FOR IE & Chrome */
}

.currencyinput input {
  border: 0;
}

input:focus {
  border-color: greenyellow;
}

input {
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-width: 1px;
  height: 24px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.form-item>input {
  width: 170px;
}
```

```html
<span class="currencyinput">$<input type="number" class="form21" id="form21" maxlength="6"></span>
```

Comment: Hey , can you send the pic of the expected result ?

Comment: I'm no genius with CSS, however I've experienced so many issues with CSS and span elements especially with positioning. The best advice I can give you is many use flex boxes and margins to correct the positioning, sorry I can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a label and position it over the element. There are other ways to do it.

```css
div.money {
  position: relative;
}

div.money label{
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: .25em;
  font-size: .9em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

div.money input {
  padding-left: .8em;
}
```

```html
<div class="money">
  <label for="num1">$</label>
  <input id="num1" type="number" />
</div>
```

Comment: While this adds some kind of information for the labeled field, it certainly is not the intended use of a label (though there can be multiple).

Comment: @connexo If `label` is not for this then you can replace it with `span`.

Answer (score -1):

```css
#form21 {
  border: none;
}

#form21:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.currencyinput {
  padding: 1px 2px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(118, 118, 118);
}
```

```html
<span class="currencyinput">
  $<input type="number" class="form21" id="form21" maxlength="6">
</span>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are almost never good answers. Your answer is no exception to this rule. Please add an explanation. Also, please don't ever provide more than a single answer to any question. Instead, edit your existing answer and explain the alternative solution, along with elaborating why one would pick either over the other.

Answer (score -2):

```css
.currencyinput > input {
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
  position: relative;
  left: -10px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<span class="currencyinput">
  $<input type="number" class="form21" id="form21" maxlength="6">
</span>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are almost never good answers. Your answer is no exception to this rule. Please add an explanation. Also, please don't ever provide more than a single answer to any question. Instead, edit your existing answer and explain the alternative solution, along with elaborating why one would pick either over the other.

Comment: This answer does fix the general appearance BUT does NOT allow users to click the field to edit the data or add new data